# 2 values from on dropdown menu option with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, contact-form

I have a dropdown menu that displays 1,2,3.....:

```
<td>
   <select id="quantity" name="quantity">
     <option value='1' id="0001">1</option>
     <option value='2' id="0002">2</option>
</td>
```

And it collects the value, with other values from the other fields in my form.. that then a jquery handler submits the values to a .php file that writes them in a mysql table:

```
...
submitHandler: function(form) {

      $(form).ajaxSubmit({
         type:"POST",
         data: $(form).serialize(),
         url:"something.php",
      }
...
```

Now i need to add to the dropdown to collect one more value id="price" like for option value="1" the price value should be something like value="100"...

Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: As seen your html is invalid(see drop down has no ending tag), also you want to handle price, explain it, whether you have element for price or not. Show us your full html so, that we can find what your exact problem is?

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to *close* your select menu!

```
<td>
<select id="quantity" name="quantity">
    <option value='1' id="0001">1</option>
    <option value='2' id="0002">2</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Then you can add your other inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" value="100" name="price" />
```

If the whole thing is wrapped in a `form` tag, and you add a submit button, then `$(form).serialize()` will turn your form into a string. So the following:

```
<form>
    <select id="quantity" name="quantity">
        <option value='1' id="0001" selected>1</option>
        <option value='2' id="0002">2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" value="100" name="price" />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        console.log($(this).serialize());
    });
</script>
```

Will output something like this to your console:

```
quantity=1&price=100
```